# Nodes start expanded when they are not supposed to

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

When I load my treegrid in jqGrid, I want to have my data collapsed, but the leafs doesn't hide even if I have "expanded:false" on each row. I have to click two times on the triangle to collapse them.

If it's a jqGrid bug, is there a way to programmatically collapse all the rows?

I'm using jqgrid 4.5.2

[image: jqgridbug]

JSON example

```
[{"SearchID":"1307101033122572934","Name":"Merisier","Count":2474,"PmpSum":1239238,"Cost":614702,"level":0,"isLeaf":false,"expanded":false,"parent":null,"Type":"SpeciesId","loaded":true,"Mpmp":496.03,"PmpAvg":500,"ID":0},
{"Count":456,"Name":"V1","PmpSum":211519,"SearchID":"1307101126533057710","Cost":115880,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":0,"PmpAvg":463,"Mpmp":547.85,"ID":1},
{"Count":476,"Name":"V2","PmpSum":234671,"SearchID":"1307101126480002486","Cost":117369,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":0,"PmpAvg":493,"Mpmp":500.14,"ID":2},
{"Count":516,"Name":"V3","PmpSum":266814,"SearchID":"1307041126098777710","Cost":127569,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":0,"PmpAvg":517,"Mpmp":478.12,"ID":3},
{"Count":520,"Name":"V5","PmpSum":261883,"SearchID":"1307101126567002934","Cost":128510,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":0,"PmpAvg":503,"Mpmp":490.72,"ID":4},
{"Count":506,"Name":"V4","PmpSum":264351,"SearchID":"1307041126002272486","Cost":125374,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":0,"PmpAvg":522,"Mpmp":474.27,"ID":5},
{"SearchID":"1307041018095682486","Name":"Tremble","Count":2492,"PmpSum":1192850,"Cost":618840,"level":0,"isLeaf":false,"expanded":false,"parent":null,"Type":"SpeciesId","loaded":true,"Mpmp":518.79,"PmpAvg":478,"ID":6},
{"Count":452,"Name":"V2","PmpSum":206778,"SearchID":"1307101126480002486","Cost":116551,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":6,"PmpAvg":457,"Mpmp":563.65,"ID":7},
{"Count":536,"Name":"V3","PmpSum":257211,"SearchID":"1307041126098777710","Cost":129121,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":6,"PmpAvg":479,"Mpmp":502,"ID":8},
{"Count":506,"Name":"V1","PmpSum":268536,"SearchID":"1307101126533057710","Cost":121648,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":6,"PmpAvg":530,"Mpmp":453,"ID":9},
{"Count":469,"Name":"V4","PmpSum":221601,"SearchID":"1307041126002272486","Cost":119857,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":6,"PmpAvg":472,"Mpmp":540.87,"ID":10},
{"Count":529,"Name":"V5","PmpSum":238724,"SearchID":"1307101126567002934","Cost":131663,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":6,"PmpAvg":451,"Mpmp":551.53,"ID":11},
{"SearchID":"1307101127175798158","Name":"Cerisier","Count":2491,"PmpSum":1288927,"Cost":622444,"level":0,"isLeaf":false,"expanded":false,"parent":null,"Type":"SpeciesId","loaded":true,"Mpmp":482.92,"PmpAvg":517,"ID":12}]
```

My grid

```
$("#InventorySummary").jqGrid({
 datatype: 'jsonstring',
 datastr: summary,
 colNames: ['ID', 'SearchId', 'Type', 'NOM', 'NBRE DE BILLOTS', 'VOL. MOYEN', 'VOLUME  EN PMP', 'TAUX/MPMP', 'MONTANT EN $ USA'],
 colModel: [
    { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', hidden: true, key: true },
    { name: 'SearchID', index: 'SearchID', hidden: true },
    { name: 'Type', index: 'Type', hidden: true },
    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name' },
    { name: 'Count', index: 'Count' },
    { name: 'PmpAvg', index: 'PmpAvg' },
    { name: 'PmpSum', index: 'PmpSum' },
    { name: 'Mpmp', index: 'Mpmp' },
    { name: 'Cost', index: 'Cost' },
 ],
 caption: "Inventory",
 height: 'auto',
 footerrow: true,
 treeGrid: true,
 treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
 ExpandColumn: 'Name',
 gridComplete: function () {
    var grid = $("#InventorySummary");
    var data = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data').filter(function (x) {
       return x.parent === null;
    });
    var count = data.reduce(function (x, y) { return x + y.Count }, 0);
    var pmpSum = data.reduce(function (x, y) { return x + y.PmpSum }, 0);
    var cost = data.reduce(function (x, y) { return x + y.Cost }, 0);
    grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Name: "TOTAUX" });
    grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Count: count });
    grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { PmpAvg: (pmpSum / count) | 0 });
    grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { PmpSum: pmpSum });
    grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Mpmp: Math.round(((cost / pmpSum) * 1000) * 100) / 100 });
    grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Cost: cost });
 },
 jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    root: function (obj) {
       return obj;
    },
 },
 onSelectRow: filterDetail,
});
```

**UPDATE:** Here's the filterDetail function. It only filter in an another grid

```
function filterDetail(id) {
  var grid = $("#InventorySummary");
  var search = [];

  do {
     search.push({ id: grid.getCell(id, 'SearchID'), type: grid.getCell(id, 'Type') });
     id = grid.getCell(id, 'parent');
  }
  while (Boolean(id));

  var newLogs = logs.filter(function (x) {
     return search.every(function (s) {
        return x[s.type] === s.id;
     });
  });
  $("#InventoryLogs").jqGrid("clearGridData").jqGrid("setGridParam", { data: newLogs, }).trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

Comment: Strange behavior, `expanded:false` should work. The fact you need to click to header twice means that grid reacts on it, but fails to collapse nodes. Did you checked console? Maybe there are some useful info.

Comment: Nothing in the console, but if I add "hiddengrid: true" like @miah say, I have the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stype' of undefined" on that line $(ts).jqGrid("SortTree", st, ts.p.sortorder, cmtypes[st].stype, cmtypes[st].srcfmt); (1661)

Comment: Ignore my previous answer.  Can you post the code for filterDetail?  I ran it on my computer and everything worked as intended, the only difference being that I had to comment out the `onSelectorRow:filterDetail`

Comment: That's weird, if I comment outt this line, I still have the same problem. I updated my post anyway

Comment: Ah whoops, I was in the wrong version (3.8.2) where it worked.  4.5.3 is not.

Comment: Looks like a bug on jqGrid side, I just added an issues on their github. On the mean time, is there a way to collapse all the rows?

Comment: @bruno updated my answer with the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After mucking about inside of jqgrid, it turns out that you need to set the parent attribute in the json to a string, and not an integer:

```
[{"SearchID":"1307101033122572934","Name":"Merisier","Count":2474,"PmpSum":1239238,"Cost":614702,"level":0,"isLeaf":false,"expanded":false,"parent":null,"Type":"SpeciesId","loaded":true,"Mpmp":496.03,"PmpAvg":500,"ID":0},
{"Count":456,"Name":"V1","PmpSum":211519,"SearchID":"1307101126533057710","Cost":115880,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":"0","PmpAvg":463,"Mpmp":547.85,"ID":1},
{"Count":476,"Name":"V2","PmpSum":234671,"SearchID":"1307101126480002486","Cost":117369,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":"0","PmpAvg":493,"Mpmp":500.14,"ID":2},
{"SearchID":"1307041018095682486","Name":"Tremble","Count":2492,"PmpSum":1192850,"Cost":618840,"level":0,"isLeaf":false,"expanded":false,"parent":null,"Type":"SpeciesId","loaded":true,"Mpmp":518.79,"PmpAvg":478,"ID":3},
{"Count":452,"Name":"V2","PmpSum":206778,"SearchID":"1307101126480002486","Cost":116551,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":"3","PmpAvg":457,"Mpmp":563.65,"ID":4},
{"Count":536,"Name":"V3","PmpSum":257211,"SearchID":"1307041126098777710","Cost":129121,"level":1,"isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"Type":"GradeId","loaded":true,"parent":"3","PmpAvg":479,"Mpmp":502,"ID":5}]
```

Comment: +1 from me. I wanted to post the same answer. The current implementation of TreeGrid works correctly only if parent are strings. jqGrid saves id as `_id_` property. The type of the property will be `string`. So the strict compare `===` for parent node works incorrect if the value of `parent` node has not `string` type too. I interpret it as a bug. Usage of `parent` as string would be a workaround.